Conditional sibling selector in CSS?
I have a <ul> with children <li>. All of the <li> are siblings. I need them all to be siblings so that htmx.takeClass(); works to highlight the active item. My layout is like this:
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush"  hx-on:click="if (event.target.classList.contains('list-group-item')) htmx.takeClass(event.target, 'active')">
    <li id="group-1" tabindex="0">Group 1</li>
    <li data-sidebar-group="group-1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-sidebar-group="group-1">Item 2</li>
    <li id="group-2" tabindex="0">Group 2</li>
</ul>

To make a sidebar, I need to select all <li> where the data-sidebar-group matches the id of another <li>. Is there any way to do this in CSS or do I need to resort to JS.
Something like li~li[data-sidebar-group=id] or li[id]~li[data-sidebar-group]. I hope you all understand my question.

Can you explain first, what are you trying to accomplish? What visual effect are you expecting? Thanks

@mariodev By default, all list items not having an id but having a data-sidebar-group will not be shown. But when a list item having an id but not having the attribute is focused on by clicking, I want all the list items that are associated with that focused list item to become visible. I just need a CSS selector to figure out which elements to make visible.

The attr function may be useful for this once it gets standardized, but it's not widely or well supported yet and is largely experimental other than for use with the property content.

I would really reconsider using flat items and instead use structured semantic html (ul > li) for the submenus. I don't think that this decision should be driven by the urge to use htmx api. It should be the other way around - use proper semantic html elements, then use css, js to align UI..

If you know that that the items that are to become visible on a focus immediately follow the focusable element, as in the given code, then you can use CSS.
This snippet has put a couple of items after the second focusable one to show the point.
Selection is done first on all the siblings following the focused one, and then removed the display of any that have another focusable one between it and the focused one.


*[data-sidebar-group] {
  display: none;
}

*:focus~*[data-sidebar-group] {
  display: block;
}

*:focus~*[tabindex]~*[data-sidebar-group] {
  display: none;
}
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" hx-on:click="if (event.target.classList.contains('list-group-item')) htmx.takeClass(event.target, 'active')">
  <li id="group-1" tabindex="0">Group 1</li>
  <li data-sidebar-group="group-1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-sidebar-group="group-1">Item 2</li>
  <li id="group-2" tabindex="0">Group 2</li>
  <li data-sidebar-group="group-2">Item 1</li>
  <li data-sidebar-group="group-2">Item 2</li>
</ul>



